# Viewpanel or regular panel with visible border?

Tags: xpages

Is there anyway to have a visible border on a view panel and a regular panel?   If so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just placing a table around the view panel.

Answer (score 1):

if you look in the web page source for the view panel you wil find that the view panel is a table , so just put some style on it e.g 
table style="border:1px solid blue"...

Comment: Where do you put it?  I but it in the viePanel tag <xp:viewPanel id="viewPanelContractor" cellpadding="1"
     cellspacing="1"
     style="border:1px solid blue"   
     >

but I get an error Description Resource Path Location Type
Unknown property style. It is not defined on tag xp:viewPanel. I was able to but the viewPanel inside a normal panel and apply the style and that seemed to work but it would be nice to be bale to do it to the viewPanel, itself

Comment: the reason you get that error is becuase you specified cellpadding and cellspacing attributes, those are not supported on the viewpanel. the style you have set should work. if you need cellspacing or cellpadding you can use e.g a stylesheet selector in your stylesheet e.g TD{padding:10px;border:1px solid red}

Comment: Try to use stylesheets instead of inline styles. like this<xpviewPanel styleClass="mystyleclass">...